# Why does CKEditor 5 replace soft hyphen &shy;? How can I stop this?

Tags: html, ckeditor5

If you add a *­* in the source code, switch back to text edit and then look into the source code again, the *­* is gone. CKEditor 5 replaces it with an invisible */u00AD*, which is still a soft hyphen.
BUT … since the Unicode character is invisible, an editor has no chance to see if and where a *­* has been added. Why does CKEditor hide this information?

In my case, I am working on a German website. We have lots of long words and the editors want to manually decide where to put soft hyphens. With CKEditor 5 they can’t do this anymore. Is there any way I can stop CKEditor from replacing *­*?

And just in case someone suggests CSS hyphen: No, we do not want CSS hyphens, because we don’t have any control where the browser adds these hyphens. It is much better if the hyphen gets added manually. At least in German.
(Example: A browser might divide the german word »Regenschauer« as »Re-genschauer« while »Regen-schauer« is easier to read.)

I think CKEditor 4 had an option to stop replacing HTML Entities with a line in the configuration. But I can’t find this option for CKEditor 5.